# This local function can be accessed outside the scope, any explanation?

Tags: function, lua, scope

```
for i = 1, 20 do  --Create a loop
  if i < 10 then 
    local function LessThan10() 
      return i
    end 
  end
end 
print(LessThan10())
```

> Surprisingly, eventhough `LessThan10` was inside a conditional statement and it was a `local` function(actually it's not the function, it's the variable). Somehow, I could still print out the answer

> This is pretty interesting (I checked in Zerobrane, `LessThan10` is a local function)

**EDIT** : Well I guess it's my interpreter problem, I changed the interpreter and this thing errors.

Comment: Nvm, my lua version was outdated, sorry guys B(

Comment: This has never worked. Perhaps you had `LessThan10` defined as a global before.

Comment: if it didn't work, I wouldn't post this question. Plus, this is based on an example from a Lua 5.1 book(I did not copy paste tho)

Comment: This was not legal code in 5.0 or 5.1. [Variables are visible until the end of the innermost block in which they are declared](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html#visibility). This was as true in 5.0 as it is in 5.4. Something else is going on. Is the "based on an example" from the visibility section linked above? There an example of a loop that fills a table with function closures is shown, but that is not what the posted code does. If not, what is this example code?

Answer (score 1):

Tested in Lua 5.0 interpreter:

```lua
Lua 5.0.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2006 Tecgraf, PUC-Rio
> for i = 1, 20 do  --Create a loop
>>   if i < 10 then
>>     local function LessThan10()
>>       return i
>>     end
>>   end
>> end
> print(LessThan10())
stdin:1: attempt to call global `LessThan10' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

I also can't believe this is / was valid code as local variables are only visible within the block they are declared at.

If you are using a custom Lua interpreter you should further investigate on it, seems pretty interesting though.

Answer (score 0):

> I tested this and it only worked on Lua 5.0 and 5.1

I tested it again on `Lua 5.3` and it no longer works

My zerobrane reset my lua version to 5.0 for no reason, well, sorry if this question disappointed you.